# How do I make bluetooth work on the Raspberry Pi3 after disable for serial gpio?

Tags: bluetooth, serial

I use serial gpio before but now want to use back the bluetooth function.How do I make bluetooth work on the Raspberry Pi3 after disable for serial gpio?

Comment: could you please make your question a little easier to understand?

Comment: Without knowing what you DID no one can tell you how to undo it.
 See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) Incidentally there is **NO NEED** to disable Bluetooth to use serial, unless you have a particularly demanding task.

Comment: i think that your question is `How do I make bluetooth work on the Raspberry Pi3` .... the rest of the stuff about serial GPIO is not really related to your question .... use google search to learn how to enable blutooth